# How to discard unsaved changes to a variant?

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

While working on a variant for /node/%node I did something that now causes a 'The requested page "/admin/structure/pages/edit/node_view" could not be found.' error and am unable to access any of the variants.

How do I discard all the changes since the last save?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer from a Drupal guru- just deleted an entry from the ctools_object_cache table in the database. Everything works fine now.